# android layout messed up suddenly

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am in the middle of developing an app and suddenly the layouts became messed up in android 2.2 and 2.3.5. But they look fine in android 4 and up.  I made some change in the layouts including some text size adjustment, padding and margin, then it messed up.  I backed up my previous working code (i always do), so I replaced it and refresh the project but the layout is still messed up.

**NOTE:** I'm using adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514

main layout

```
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/top_date_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/first_page_top_white_bar_padding_top"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/first_page_top_white_bar_padding_button">

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/update_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/refresh_icon"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/titlebar_first_icon_margin_right"/>

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/clock_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/clock_icon"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/titlebar_other_icon_margin_right"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/date_from_web_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/clock_image"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/date_from_web_string"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/first_page_helal_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:background="@drawable/first_page_helal_icon_background"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_date_bar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/first_page_helal_layout_padding_left_right"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/first_page_helal_layout_padding_left_right"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/first_page_helal_layout_padding_top_buttom"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/first_page_helal_layout_padding_top_buttom"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/first_page_helal_layout_margin_top">

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/moon_image"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/helal_image_maxwidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/helal_image_maxwidth"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/moon_icon"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/helal_image_margin_right"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/first_page_month_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/moon_image"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/moharam"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/helal_image_margin_right"/>

        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/maalomat_helal_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/first_page_month_text"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/first_page_maalomat_helal_string"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/first_page_expand_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:layout_below="@id/first_page_helal_layout" 
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/first_page_expand_list_margin_top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/first_page_expand_list_margin_left_right"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/first_page_expand_list_margin_left_right"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent"
        android:divider="@color/transparent"
        android:childDivider="@color/transparent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

group view

```
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/innerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/group_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Group Title"          
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/first_page_group_margin_right"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/group_icon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/first_page_button_icon_maxwidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/first_page_button_icon_maxwidth"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/date_icon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/first_page_group_margin_left"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/group_lines"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/first_page_button_lines_maxheight"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/group_icon"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/blue_lines_icon"
            android:alpha="0.1"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/expandable_image"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/first_page_expand_icon_maxwidth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/first_page_expand_icon_maxheight"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_below="@id/innerLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/expand_icon"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

child view

```
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/child_title"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Child Title"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

android 4.2
[image]

android 2.2
[image]

Comment: how can we help you with no .xml file posted?

Comment: Remember people are not pyschic and have no special powers. So always include everything you can so we can get a "context" of your problem.

Comment: i will post it in a minute, but i'm sure it's not the code problem, the code that worked 2 hours ago now is messed up.

Comment: have you cleaned the project and restartet eclipse/android studio?

Comment: @A.S. : how i can clean the project? restarting eclipse and even pc didn't help

Comment: I have no idea what "messed up" means here. Is everything pink with purple polka dots?

Comment: menu bar project->clean

Comment: @Tanis.7x : wait a minute, i will post screen shots

Comment: You will need to know how to clean a project to develop. Google it.

Comment: @A.S. : cleaning didn't help

Comment: @Tanis.7x : see the pictures, android 4.2 looks fine, but in android 2.2 messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, updated to ADT-22.3.0
problem solved